# How to save automatically in 2 different format without dialog

Tags: vba

I have a huge documents (.doc) in c:\sample folder. I want to save them in .docx, .pdf, .txt to c:\sample_converted folder after changing the font.

I have VBA script to change the font and it works fine..However got stuck in saving them in different format as well as without save dialog

I want to do this conversion entirely without user intervention. If not possible, at-least user can be requested for the source and target folder once.

```
    strName = Left(oDoc.FullName, InStrRev(oDoc.FullName, ".") - 1) & ".txt"
    oDoc.Range.Font.Name = strFont
    oDoc.Save
    oDoc.SaveAs2 FileName:=strName, FileFormat:=wdFormatUnicodeText
    strName = Left(oDoc.FullName, InStrRev(oDoc.FullName, ".") - 1) & ".docx"
    oDoc.Save
    oDoc.SaveAs2 FileName:=strName, FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocument
    oDoc.Close SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
    WordBasic.DisableAutoMacros 0
```

Please advise how to do this.

Thanks.

Comment: Try `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` before saving.

Comment: Did you specify the file type for each save line? Where is your code?

Comment: @brax added the code for your reference

Comment: `code` SaveAs2  does not work with Word 2007. For 2007 and previous change the line

oDoc.SaveAs2 FileName:=strName, FileFormat:=wdFormatUnicodeText, Encoding:=65001

to

oDoc.SaveAs FileName:=strName, FileFormat:=wdFormatUnicodeText, Encoding:=65001

<=2007 is SaveAs
>2007 is SaveAs

Answer (score 0):

SaveAs2  does not work with Word 2007. For 2007 and previous change the line

oDoc.SaveAs2 FileName:=strName, FileFormat:=wdFormatUnicodeText, Encoding:=65001

to

oDoc.SaveAs FileName:=strName, FileFormat:=wdFormatUnicodeText, Encoding:=65001

<=2007 is SaveAs and >2007 is SaveAs2

Now it works well.